# Is stem cell therapy effective against chronic Lyme Disease?

Tags: medical-science

[Infusio](https://www.infusio.org/) is an organisation that claim to treat [Lyme Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease).

The founder, Phillip Batiade, shares his opinion on Lyme disease treatment in [this video](https://youtu.be/jRaRfUPPEz0).

The main claims he makes, as far as I understand, are that the treatment is effective in "85% of people; only 10% of patients does not heal completely, but their situation improves enough that they can partially resume their life." It is not clear to me what the 5% between "fully effective" and "not healing completely" is, but let's take these numbers at face value.

There are aspects that I am suspicious of - many of the clinics are in poorly regulated locations, the price is high, insurance companies won't cover it.

Does Infusio's approach, based in part on stem cell therapy, treat chronic Lyme Disease?

Comment: A better question may be "Is chronic Lyme disease a real thing?"

Comment: @JasonR would you mind to elaborate? I am pretty sure people have chronic symptoms from Lyme's disease, when untreated. So are you saying it is chronic by definition, or do you mean it's no longer Lyme at that point?

Comment: wait!? That person isn't [getting treated](https://www.webmd.com/rheumatoid-arthritis/arthritis-lyme-disease) as recommended?!?!?! What I doubt is that people still claim Lyme disease affects them chronically after treatment.

Comment: To clear up what I think @JasonR is saying: [Chronic Lyme Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronic_Lyme_disease) is basically a medically condition once believed to be from persistent presence of Lyme disease in a treated patient, however it is no longer believed to have any medical merit. Chronic symptoms from [untreated Lyme disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease#Late_disseminated_infection) are definitely a thing, but 'Chronic Lyme Disease' is not something that actually happens to treated patients.

Comment: Yes, Giter explained it much more clearly than I did!

Comment: As written, this is more of a Health.SE question.  What is the claim by a notable source?

Comment: That "No responsibility is taken for any inaccurate information published on or linked to this site" disclaimer at the bottom of Infusio's website should be cause for concern, especially when plunking down $40k. Legitimate medical providers don't have a need for that sort of disclaimer.

Comment: The vast majority of stem-cell therapies can be summarized as "inject stem cells and pray for a miracle".

Comment: @ceejayoz They should. A website is not a replacement for the tailored advice of a professional, and a disclaimer is meant to say such.

Comment: @fredsbend You won't see such a disclaimer on a drug manufacturer's website, or the Mayo Clinic's medical info pages. "You should see a doctor about this stuff" is legit - "we're not responsible if this is all bullshit" isn't.

Comment: @Giter  What do these patients have then? That Wiki article concedes these patients have symptoms but explains nothing.

Comment: @fredsbend Wikipedia answers that. "The symptoms represent 'for all intents and purposes' fibromyalgia or chronic fatigue syndrome." I wouldn't dismiss the possibility of psychogenic illness, either.

Comment: @cee Those are just Latin words that describe the symptoms. FM and CFS are as slippery as Chronic lyme.

Comment: @fredsbend Fibromyalgia and chronic fatigue are recognized by the medical community, to the point of having ICD-10 codes. "Chronic lyme" is not, and the suggested mechanism is both debunkable and *debunked*.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I've made a significant edit to the question - please take a look. We aren't a self-help site, so I have taken the focus away from your friend's plight (hope they get better soon). I haven't been able to find where the cure rate claims are made. I want to make the claim more specific, because it isn't reasonable to make everyone watch a waffling 6 minute video where he doesn't actually make a claim about the effects of his treatment.

Comment: I also focused on (so called) chronic Lyme Disease, because acute Lyme doesn't require that sort of treatment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stem cell therapy may be effective in treating Lyme disease, however the safety and efficacy of such treatments in currently unproven due to how recent they are.

In at least one case report, stem cell therapy was effective at treating long-term complications from untreated Lyme Disease. However, the results of this and other case reports have only recently become available for study, and stem cell therapy doesn't appear to have comprehensive studies proving safety and efficacy.

Because of this, Infusio's claims should be taken with a large amount of suspicion, and their stem cell treatment plan may not be as effective as they are claiming. However, Infusio also seems to have a normal Lyme Disease treatment plan using standard antibiotics(with some extra comforting fluff thrown in), so that plan should be mostly trustworthy(and probably overpriced).

---

**Lyme Disease vs. 'Chronic' Lyme Disease:** Lyme Disease is [a bacterial infection typically spread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease#Cause) by certain ticks. Untreated Lyme Disease causes [a lot of awful chronic problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease#Late_disseminated_infection), however a round or two of antibiotics is generally enough to treat the infection.

[Chronic Lyme Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronic_Lyme_disease) is something that is no longer considered a medical condition, though treatments for it continue to be advertised by sketchy alternative medicine providers. As [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4490322/pdf/civ186.pdf) demonstrates, questionable medical providers advertise various treatments for both normal and Chronic Lyme Disease, including stem cell therapy. These treatments generally have little scientific backing or rationale, as stated in the paper:

> Scientific studies supporting the efficacy of any of the treatments
>   discussed above could not be found on review of
>   the medical literature. Most of the cited treatments were never
>   evaluated with any scientific study, although we did find that a
>   few treatments were evaluated in studies that either were poorly
>   designed or had unclear relevance to human disease.

Although Infusio is not mentioned in the above paper, similar treatments were given less than positive reviews by the autors:

> Testimonials in online patient networks referenced
>   having received stem cell transplantation for Lyme disease
>   at clinics in India, Panama, Bermuda, Costa Rica, and
>   the United States.
>
> ...
>
> ...exposure to reactive oxygen species in the forms of
>   ozone or peroxide, chelation therapy, intravenous silver infusion,
>   and stem cell transplantation pose significant risks to
>   patients.

**Stem Cell Therapy for Lyme Disease:** As to whether or not stem cell therapy actually works for treating Lyme Disease: it's a very recent treatment, and the safety/efficacy is mostly unkown. [This case report](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5986024/pdf/CCR3-6-1166.pdf) gives a pretty rosy picture of stem cell therapy, describing a successful treatment:

> The patient’s Lyme disease symptoms have also
>   improved. He no longer complains of significant fatigue
>   or insomnia, and only requires low dose Adderall for his
>   ADHD (5 mg/day) to help concentrate at school. There is
>   mild neck and back pain, but it is positional, with no
>   other associated joint pain or neuropathy...  He has remained clinically stable without relapses
>   while off all antibiotics, and only required a seven-day
>   course of a cephalosporin for a sinus infection during his
>   first year of college.

This is a promising example for stem cell therapy, and therefore Infusio's treatment program might actually be as effective as they claim. However, this report presents major red flags for Infusio, as summed up in the report's conclusion section:

> We report the first successful improvement of CVID in a
>   patient with Lyme disease using human embryonic stem
>   cell therapy. Further studies are necessary to evaluate the
>   safety and efficacy of hSCT in reversing CVID...

In short, this case reports seems to be presenting the *first* successful stem cell treatment of long-term untreated Lyme Disease complications, and outright state that further studies are needed in order to say such a treatment is safe and effective enough to be used in general. Considering this report came out in February of this year, I doubt comprehensive studies backing up Infusio's claims have been made.

**Infusio and Chronic Lyme Disease:** Although Infusio's Lyme Disease treatment page doesn't currently make any claim regarding Chronic Lyme Disease treatments, they certainly used to offer treatments for it. I'm not sure how recently they made the change, but they still haven't change all of the titles in their site's source code:

[image: Infusio site source code, showing Chronic Lyme Disease claim]

So, at best they were questionable in the past and have now changed their practices to treat actual medical conditions using recent and semi-proven treatments. At worst, they still use medically unsound treatments and just don't tell you about it.

---

**Addition:** I just checked [a version of the Infusio site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811102621/http://www.infusio.org:80/medical/lyme-disease/) from August 2017 on Wayback's archives, and in regards to Chronic Lyme Disease they are mostly right:

[image: Old Infusio Lyme claims]

A version from 2016 is similar. They certainly are talking about treating chronic problems from *untreated* Lyme Disease, which is a real thing, rather than offering treatment for the debunked version. Infusio's normal Lyme Disease treatment plan seems trustworthy, though the stem cell therapy is still questionable.

Comment: Great answer. Check the wayback for an archive of that page.

Comment: @fredsbend: Good idea! I just checked the archive and added it to the answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's a nice comprehensive answer, and actually more of a 'maybe' and less of a 'definitely no' than I was expecting. Also thanks a lot for clarifying some of the points that were not clear to me and therefore sparked some discussion in the comments. I'll leave the question open for a few more days to invite anyone to an alternative response but I would definitely upvote twice if I could.